Фильтр одного столбца на основе другого Google таблицы
подскажите пожалуйста формулу.
есть столбец A со списком транзакций (100 штук)
и другой столбец B со списком транзакций (20 штук)
транзакции из столбцов точно совпадают.
Нужно чтобы А схлопнулся и в столбце А остались только строки совпадения между А и Б

В фильтр добавить доп. столбец с формулой:
-- если нужны совпадения построчно:
=A2=B2

-- если в столбце A отобразить только те, которые есть в столбце B:
=СЧЁТЕСЛИ(B:B;A2)>0

